# To prove the polynomial mapping is linear

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, linear-transformations

Show that the mapping $L : P_2 \to P_2$ given by $$L(p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2
) = p_1 + p_0x +(p_0 + 2p_1 − p_2)x^2$$
is linear and provide the matrix representing $L$ (with respect
to the basis $\{1, x, x^2\}$).

Comment: Please show what have you done, and let us now if you have problem with any of the concepts.

Comment: I am not sure on how to proceed with this question i know the properties T(u + v) = T(u) + T(v) for all u, v ∈ V , (1)
T(av) = aT(v) for all a ∈ F and v ∈ V but I am not able to apply it in the poiynomial equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Additivity:

$$ L(p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2 ) = p_1 + p_0x + (p_0 + 2p_1 − p_2)x^2$$

$$ L(q_0 + q_1x + q_2x^2 ) = q_1 + q_0x + (q_0 + 2q_1 − q_2)x^2$$

Then $$ L((p_0+q_0) + (p_1+q_1) x + (p_2+q_2) x^2 ) = (p_1+q_1)  + (p_0+q_0) x + ((p_0+q_0)  + 2(p_1+q_1)  − (p_2+q_2) )x^2=$$
$$ = p_1 + p_0x + (p_0 + 2p_1 − p_2)x^2+q_1 + q_0x + (q_0 + 2q_1 − q_2)x^2 =$$
$$ =L(p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2 )+ L(q_0 + q_1x + q_2x^2 )$$

Homogeneity: 
$$ L(a(p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2) ) = ap_1 + ap_0x + (ap_0 + a2p_1 − ap_2)x^2= aL(p_0 + p_1x + p_2x^2 )$$

Matrix:

$$L (1) = x+x^2$$
$$L(x) = 1+2x^2$$
$$L(x^2) = -x^2$$

$$L = \begin{pmatrix}
0 &1 &0 \\
1& 0& 0\\
1& 2& -1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: How did get the equation L(1)=x+x2 
L(x)=1+2x2
L(x2)=−x2 and the matrix, would be helpful if you could elaborate.

Comment: $$L(1+0x+0x^2) = 0+1x+(1+2\cdot 0-0)x^2$$ and so on

Comment: Got it , Thankyou.

Comment: Can you please help me out in obtaining matrix from differentiation mapping?s T p(z) = p′(z). Then for
two polynomials p(z), q(z) ∈ P(F) we have
T(p(z) + q(z)) = (p(z) + q(z))′ = p′(z) + q′(z) = T(p(z)) + T(q(z)).
and for homogeneity 
T(ap(z)) = (ap(z))′ = ap′(z) = aT(p(z)).

Comment: What you did is correct. There is nothing more to add